# Building a Qt/QML app for Windows distribution

Tags: qt, qml

I have spent about a week trying to figure out what should be a very straightforward and common process for building a Qt app for Windows distribution. I would expect that Qt has options in the Build & Run settings page to ensure that the build directory contains standalone dlls of the shared Qt libraries, but I cannot figure out the steps to make this so. Ideally, I could just zip up the build directory and give it to someone and they could run it even if Qt is not installed on their system.

I've seen the Qt Windows deployment page but I was advised to ignore that by some generous fellows on the Qt forums, yet I haven't received enough details to accomplish this seemingly simple and common goal. Additionally, the Windows deployment page seemed to offer a specific strategy relating to Visual Studio, but I'm using MinGW.

One guy suggested I actually compile Qt entirely from its source to accomplish this, but this lengthy and complex process was later dismissed by someone else, so in the end I just keep going in circles trying to find the right information.

I installed Qt for Windows with MinGW on this page: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Can anyone point me in the right direction with some actionable details? Surely this is a very simple and common requirement for anyone writing something in Qt so I'm not sure why the solution is so elusive!

Comment: Personnally I use Inno Setup to build an installer for my app on Windows. And I manually copy the mandatory dll/files for my app to run properly on a Windows without Qt (manually meaning I did not find one Qt command line to do it so had to add them to the script one by one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QT Version 5.1.0
Necessary .dll files for MinGw compiled project in release mode
```

files under "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin"

```
-icudt51.dll
-icuin51.dll
-icuuc51.dll
-libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
-libstdc++-6.dll
-libwinpthread-1.dll
-Qt5Core.dll

(and depending on which additional components used)
-Qt5Gui.dll
-Qt5SerialPort.dll
-Qt5Widgets.dll
-Qt5Qml.dll
 .
 .
 .
```

files under "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\plugins\platforms"

```
/platform       
--qminimal.dll
--qwindows.dll

put the executable in same folder with these dlls.
```